# Взаимодействовать с браузером пользователя

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Если пользователь ввел цифру 2, то ему должна открыться страница google, но я так понимаю, что webbrowser.open_new(r"google.com") взаимодействует с моим браузером и, когда пользователь ввел 2, то страница гугла открывается у меня. Как я могу взаимодействовать с браузером пользователя и открыть ссылку у него?

```
            elif response == "2":
                vk_session.method('messages.send',
                                          {'user_id': event.user_id, 'message': 'Открываю ссылку\n\n' + if_message, 'random_id': 0})
                webbrowser.open_new(r"google.com")
```

Comment: ну правильно, что она у вас открывается вы же скрипт запускаете не пользователь P.s сомневаюсь что можно как то реализовать открытие каких либо браузеров или программ у пользователей удаленно через вк

Comment: Если Вы хотите открыть сайт у пользователя который пишет Вашему боту в ВК - то никак. Сценарий Вы запускаете у себя и браузер открыть можете тоже только у себя.